# loop over a list for specific(say first 3) values and then loop again for the next (next 3) values and iterate till the end in django template

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary, templates

my view:

```
def dashboard(request):
    buses = get_bus_of_substation(request)
    data = []
    key = 1
    for bus in buses:
        for i in range(25):
            dt = datetime.datetime.today()
            tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=-i)
            dt = dt + tdelta
            date_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
            # print(date_time)
            sub_equip_id = bus.substation_equipment_id
            volt_value = get_voltage(date_time, sub_equip_id)
            # for volt in volt_value:
            #     print(volt.val)
            if volt_value:
                data.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                data.append(dt.strftime('%H:00:00'))
                for volt in volt_value:
                    data.append(volt.val)
                break
        if not volt_value:
            data.append('No Data')
            data.append('No Data')
            data.append('No Data')
    my_iter = iter(data)
    grouped_list = zip(my_iter, my_iter, my_iter)
    transformers = get_transformer_of_substation(request)

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context={'buses': buses, 'transformers': transformers, 'grouped_list': grouped_list})
```

my template:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Bus Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Hour</th>
        <th scope="col">Voltage(kV)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for bus in buses %}
    <tr class="table-active">

        <td>{{ bus.bus_name }}</td>
        {% for a,b,c in grouped_list %}
        <td>{{ a }}</td>
        <td>{{ b }}</td>
        <td>{{ c }}</td>
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to print first three list_values in the first row and the next three list_values in the next row and so on. but the grouped_list is printing all the values in one single row. Please suggest me what to do

Comment: Why is your dictionary a dictionary if its key's are simply 1,2,3... Use a **list** instead...

Comment: can i load a list in django template in the same manner as a dictionary. and how to access a list inside a template?

Comment: `{% for object in my_list %} {{ object }} {% endfor %}`... Please show your view.

Comment: ok, list will be better option, i understand. but using list, how can i iterate in the similar fashion i asked in my question?

Comment: Is your use case like there is a list of buses and you want to render their `data` that is for them? This turns out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This is why you should properly state what your problem is exactly.

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience. Yes, for each bus name i need three values from my list to show in each row. and for the next bus name i need to show the next three values of my list. how can i do it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Do check.

Answer (score 0):

A trick commonly used to iterate over a list in groups is to make an iterator and zip it with itself. As an example:

```
def my_view(request):
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    my_iter = iter(my_list)
    grouped_list = zip(my_iter, my_iter, my_iter)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'grouped_list': grouped_list})
```

Now in the template we can simply loop over this zip object:

```
{% for a, b, c in grouped_list %}
    <td>{{ a }}</td>
    <td>{{ b }}</td>
    <td>{{ c }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**: Looking at your view it appears that you wanted to do something completely different than what you describe. You have a list `buses` and want to display the `data` you compute for that if I am correct. In this case you should make a proper data structure to be able to render properly in the template. For instance a structure like `[{'bus': bus, 'bus_data': bus_data}, (Similar objects here)]` would be more apt for your usage:

In your view do something like follows:

```
def dashboard(request):
    buses = get_bus_of_substation(request)
    data = []
    key = 1
    for bus in buses:
        bus_data = []
        for i in range(25):
            dt = datetime.datetime.today()
            tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=-i)
            dt = dt + tdelta
            date_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
            sub_equip_id = bus.substation_equipment_id
            volt_value = get_voltage(date_time, sub_equip_id)
            if volt_value:
                bus_data.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                bus_data.append(dt.strftime('%H:00:00'))
                for volt in volt_value:
                    bus_data.append(volt.val)
                break
        if not volt_value:
            bus_data.append('No Data')
            bus_data.append('No Data')
            bus_data.append('No Data')
        data.append({'bus': bus, 'bus_data': bus_data})
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context={'transformers': transformers, 'data': data})
```

Now in the template you can loop over `data` like so:

```
{% for bus_dict in data %}
<tr class="table-active">
    <td>{{ bus_dict.bus.bus_name }}</td>
    {% for value in bus_dict.bus_data %}
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it and I think i am this much close.
I am trying this:

{% for bus in buses %}
    <tr class="table-active">
        <td>{{ bus.bus_name }}</td>
        {% for a,b,c in grouped_list %}
        <td>{{ a }}</td>
        <td>{{ b }}</td>
        <td>{{ c }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
I want to print only first three values in the first row and the next three values in the next row and so on. But its printing all the values in one single row. Please suggest me a way.

Comment: @TaufiqueAlam [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67119762/edit) your question and add your view and this template code there...

Comment: Zajakallahu Khairan. That worked very well. Thanks for all the time. I understood about XY Problem. I would be more descriptive about my questions in the near future.